# Agrupando por dia e pelo período da data

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Tenho uma query do período de 26 a 30-06 que traz o seguinte resultado:

```
Data_Cancelado     Cancelados
27-06-2017             4
29-06-2017             5
```

Porém, eu quero que venha dessa maneira, ou seja,quero que venha na consulta os todos os dias independente se tem ou não registro.

```
Data_Cancelado     Cancelados
26-06-2017             0
27-06-2017             4
28-06-2017             0
29-06-2017             5
30-06-2017             0
```

A query é a seguinte:

```
select
CONVERT(DATE,S.SolDataFechamento,103) [DATA_Cancelado],
COUNT (S.SolID) [Cancelados]
from Solicitacao S
where S.ProID = 4 and S.SolEstagioID = 110  and S.SolDataFechamento BETWEEN '26-06-2017' AND '30-06-2017' 
group by CONVERT(DATE,S.SolDataFechamento,103)
```

Comment: tá dando erro de conversão? acho que o que tem que fazer é  **where S.SolDataFechamento BETWEEN '02/24/2017' AND '08/18/2017'**.. ou seja, comparar as datas no formato do banco MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: não amigo, não tem nada a ver com conversão não. Quero que venha na consulta os todos os dias independente se tem ou não registro.

Comment: @RenanBessa como armazena essa informações?

Comment: @RenanBessa: a coluna `SolDataFechamento` está declarada como date ou como datetime? Se declarada como datetime, ela contém somente data ou contém data e horário?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Renan, eis sugestão que primeiro agrupa as linhas que atendam aos requisitos para somente após complementar as ausências.

O período de emissão é informado logo no início do código, o que evita a necessidade de modificar no meio do código para alterar o período de emissão. Isto facilita a utilização do código.

```
-- código #2
--> informe datas inicial e final (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @dataInicial date, @dataFinal date;
set @dataInicial= convert(date, '26/6/2017', 103);
set @dataFinal= convert(date, '30/6/2017', 103);

with 
-- contabiliza cancelamentos
cteCancelados as (
SELECT convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103) as SolDataFechamento,
       count(SolID) as Cancelados
  from Solicitacao
  where ProID = 4 
        and SolEstagioID = 110
        and convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103) between @dataInicial and @dataFinal 
  group by convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103)
),
-- gera período
cteDatas as (
SELECT @dataInicial as dataPeríodo
union all
SELECT dateadd(day, +1, dataPeríodo)
  from cteDatas 
  where dataPeríodo < @dataFinal
)
SELECT convert(char(10), D.dataPeríodo, 103) as DATA_Cancelado,
       coalesce(S.Cancelados, 0) as Cancelados
  from cteDatas as D
       left join contaSolID as S on S.SolDataFechamento = D.dataPeríodo;
```

---

Caso a coluna SolDataFechamento esteja declarada como *datetime*, você pode alterar:

```
- convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103) para cast(SolDataFechamento as date)
```

Isto torna a cláusula WHERE *sargable*.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz assim, uma query que recebe todas as tabas primeiro. depois vem o select com um `sum case`

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATE
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATE

SET @StartDateTime = '01/05/2017'
SET @EndDateTime = '01/06/2017';

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT DateData,
    sum(case when CONVERT(DATE,S.SolDataFechamento,103) = CONVERT(DATE,DateData,103) then COUNT(s.solid) else 0 end) as qtd
FROM DateRange, Solicitacao S
group by DateData
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
```

Comment: É verdade.. não tinha visto tua resposta.. e a sua está com o where completo dele.. parabéns!